# Why do I have to double click so that the onclick changes happen?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.body.style.background = 'white';

function changeMood() {
  document.body.style.background === 'white' ?
    document.body.style.background = 'rgb(20, 20, 20)' :
    document.body.style.background = 'white';
}
```

```html
<section class="mode" onclick="changeMood()">
  <i id="mood-icon" class="fas fa-adjust fa-2x">click</i>
</section>
```

Why do I have to double click so that the onclick changes happen?

Comment: Your code works fine, no double click needed

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use a ternary statement in place of an `if` here; it might _work_ but it reads terribly

Comment: @Phil Nothing wrong with conditional operator if done properly IMO. `const { style } = document.body; style.background = style.background === 'white' ? 'rgb(20, 20, 20) : 'white'` but toggling a class would be more elegant

Comment: @CertainPerformance Using a ternary to assign a value based on alternating state  . Using a ternary to execute different statements (IMO) 

Comment: @SebastionSimon I don't see how either of those duplicates apply to this question

Comment: One of them is *probably* what's actually happening on OP's side, but there's no MCVE, maybe a miscopy or something.